# Refresh date in Broadcast Receiver Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a broadcast receiver class which I call at the beginning of a new day.

Here is the broadcast receiver onReceive method.

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(NEW_DAY_FROM_RECEIVER));

    Log.d(TAG, "Old day passed, new day in!");

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d");
    Date yesterdaysDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);
    String yesterdaysDateString = dateFormat.format(yesterdaysDate);

// Saving the value 
    DailyPointsItem yesterdayPointsItem = new DailyPointsItem(yesterdaysDateString, String.valueOf(pointsForToday), notEatenItemsArrayList, DailyPointsItem.DAILY_FOOD_POINT);

    Log.d(TAG,"Points: " + yesterdayPointsItem.getTitle() + " : " + yesterdayPointsItem.getDescription());

    addDailyPointsItem(context, yesterdayPointsItem);

 }

 public static void addDailyPointsItem(Context context, DailyPointsItem yesterdayPointsItem) {

    ArrayList<DailyPointsItem> dailyPointsDataList = SharedPreferencesManager.getDailyPointsItemsArrayList(context);

    dailyPointsDataList.add(0, yesterdayPointsItem);

    if(dailyPointsDataList.size()==8){
        dailyPointsDataList.remove(7);
    }


    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonDailyPointsArray = gson.toJson(dailyPointsDataList);

    editor.putString(JSON_STRING_POINTS_ARRAY, jsonDailyPointsArray);

    editor.apply();



}
```

Here I store the string yesterdaysDateString (which is the string of the previous day that just passed), and display this data some place else.

This broadcast receiver I call at the begining of each day using an AlarmManager, called in my Main Activity when the app starts, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewDayReceiver.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


if (!calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent); //Repeat every 24 hours
            Log.d(TAG, "New day alarm set for:" + calendar.getTime() + " and will repeat every day");
        }
```

Now this works fine, and each day that comes in the date is stored in the string. However the date is only correctly saved if the app is opened each day. If the app isn't opened each day, the AlarmManager works and the broadcast receiver is called, however the date that is saved is the date of the last day the app was open. If for example the app was opened Sun, Mar 25, and not opened for 3 days. then the three dates that are stored are Sun, Mar 25. Why is the Broadcast receiver not saving the current date.

EDITED: It works when the phone is used, but if the phone isn't used and left idle, it doesn't save the correct date. Why would this be so?

Comment: post code for saving data also please

Comment: @quicklearner Added code. Thanks

Comment: read this answer, this may be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199362/custom-notification-center